# Selenium command taking more time than specified in wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium test to navigate to a login page. Enter user name and password and click the login button. Once logged in, check whether an element is present in the home page.
I am keeping track of the time each command takes

```
WebDriver driver = driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("<url>");

WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
```

Even though my wait is for 20 seconds, When I check the total time for this command to execute it can take up to 30 (this happens on failed logins). I am trying to figure out why selenium is taking 30 seconds instead of 20 in case of failures? I read through the documentation etc but no where did I see that `pageLoadTimeout` impacts loading when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `driver.get("<url>");` command takes some time.

Means the page needs some time to load. You could load the page threaded tho.